# Tensorflow: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow11GetNodeAttrERKNS_9AttrSliceEN4absl14lts_2020_09_2311string_viewEPSs

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm trying to follow this tensorflow [tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/decision-forests/blob/main/documentation/tutorials/beginner_colab.ipynb#scrollTo=52W45tmDjD64).
However when I try the second piece of code it fails with the following error:

```
NotFoundError: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_decision_forests/tensorflow/ops/training/training.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow11GetNodeAttrERKNS_9AttrSliceEN4absl14lts_2020_09_2311string_viewEPSs
```

When I did my research I found [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/text/issues/385) GitHub issue. So I also tried to change the version in colab but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try to uninstall tensorflow (in mine colab it was 2.6.0) install tf 2.5.0 and then install tensorflow_decision_forests.